# Grabbing an image from a URL, then passing it to an API as a file in multipart form data

Tags: node.js, image, api, url, multipartform-data

So I have a URL that contains an image, and I want to pass that image as part of multipart form data to an API (to be specific, if it matters, the ClickUp API). I'm doing all of this inside of a Figma plugin, which is a browser environment.

The url looks something like https://s3-alpha-sig.figma.com....

The request works perfectly for a local image that I add manually, such as in Postman. Here is the code for a successful Postman request to this endpoint:

```
var axios = require('axios');
var FormData = require('form-data');
var fs = require('fs');
var data = new FormData();
data.append('attachment', fs.createReadStream('7UI7S5-pw/fdb54856-9c05-479f-b726-016ef252d9f5.png'));
data.append('filename', 'example.png');

var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://api.clickup.com/api/v2/task/2phh5bf/attachment',
  headers: { 
    'Authorization': '(my auth token)', 
    ...data.getHeaders()
  },
  data : data
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
```

However, I don't have access to local files and need to upload from a URL, so here's what I've done so far:

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('attachment', open(imgURL));
data.append('filename', 'screenshot.png');

fetch(`(the URL)`, {
"method": "POST",
"muteHttpExceptions": true,
 "headers": {
'Authorization': '(my auth token)', 
...data.headers
},
data: data
}).then(response => {
console.log(response)
})
```

How should I be converting the URL into something I can input as Form Data? Thanks so much in advance!